# Non-Salticidae with °oo° Eye Arrangements

Tags: species-identification, eyes, arachnology

Since childhood, I've always thought of the °oo° pattern of four frontmost eyes as iconic for spiders (note: the pattern does not account for any additional eyes or lack thereof further to the sides or back; also, title font seems to make the °'s relatively smaller than the main text's font does - this was not intentional). And yet taking a look at a couple of eye-based family identification tables, it seems that the above pattern is the go-to sign of a jumping spider.

Is this pattern unique to salticidae, or are there other groups of spiders with the four foremost eyes matching such a pattern (either four equal-sized eyes, or the secondary ones slightly smaller)? If the latter, what groups sport a similar look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty much unique to salticidae, although I did find some similar eye arrangements in sicariids and scytodids.

Salticidae:

[image]

Sicariidae:

[image]

Scytodidae:

[image]

[Image source](https://bugguide.net/node/view/84423)